# .on('click') in for loop to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with my function. I need a for loop to attach a click event to my elements. Now it sadly only adds the click event to the last element.

I did it like this right now:

```
var $texte = $('.text-bg');

            $texte = $texte.children();
            for(i=0;i<$texte.length;i++){
            switch($($texte[i]).attr('class')){

                case 'text-top-left':
                console.log($texte[i]);
                    $($texte[i]).on('click', function(){
                        $($texte[i]).toggle(
                            function(){$($texte[i]).animate({'left':'0'})}, 
                            function(){$($texte[i]).animate({'left':'-100px'})}
                            );
                            });
                break;
            }
            }
```

But somehow the click event doesnt save. So when it goes into the second loop in the for function, the first click event is being overwritten. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `this` inside the event handler to refer to the current element

```
$($clicker[i]).on('click', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        'left': '0'
    });
});
```

Why is your solution not working

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
- [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

---

The given code can be changed as(there is no need to has a switch statement here)

```
var $texte = $('.text-bg');

$texte.children('.text-top-left').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        flag = $this.data('animToggle');
    $this.data('animToggle', !flag);
    $this.animate({
        'left': flag ? '0' : '-100px'
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lhe9wLho/)

Comment: I edited my code, it some how is not working. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: [.toggle(function, function, ... )] is [removed in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)

Comment: The edit you posted works, the problem is I have atleast 2 cases. That's why I needed the switch. One time I have to animate from the right, and the other time from the left side. Is there a way to change your code to this? And could you post a resource so I could understand what you did?

Comment: @FrederikWitte if you can post the updated code, we can have a look

Comment: Hey, I just used ur code($this insead of $($texte[i])). I think its okay like it is right now. The only problem is its flickering now. When I first click it it works just fine, but when I click it again, its jumping left and right.

Comment: @FrederikWitte jumping left & right? can you share the updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61880/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-frederik-witte).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `this`, In event handler it refers to element which executed the event.

*Use*

```
$($clicker[i]).on('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({'left':'0'}); //Used this here
});
```

Your code can be simplified as However [.toggle(function, function, ... ) removed in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)

```
$('.text-bg > .text-top-left').on('click', function() {
    var toggle = $(this).data('toggle');
    $(this).data('toggle', !toggle);
    $(this).animate({
        'left': toggle ? '-100px' : '0'
    });
});
```

Comment: I edited my code, it some how is not working. Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to attach the handler to all jQuery result elements at once:

```
$clicker.on('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({'left':'0'}); //Used this here
});
```

With your updated code, you should use the selection facilities already provided by jQuery:

```
$('.text-bg > .text-top-left').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggle(
    function() {
     $(this).animate( {'left':'0'})}, 
      function() {
       $(this).animate({'left':'-100px'})
      });
    });
 });
```

To add a second case (for another class) just 'double' the code with the alternative behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$($texte[i]).on('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({'left':'0'});
});
```

OR simply assign the loop variable to a local variable INSIDE the loop:

```
var j = i;
$($texte[j]).on('click', function(){
    $($texte[j]).animate({'left':'0'});
});
```